# Webview runtime setup while wpf app installation

Tags: wpf

I am deploying my wpf exe file using VS 2019 setup project. I am using webview2 in my wpf and I am able to see the result however my client machine is not able get any result .
Is there any way apart from what is mentioned in webview runtime documents mentioned by Microsoft.

Any simple way to install webview while user is installing the wpf setup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer [Webview distribution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution) 
There are 2 way to get the root cause,

1. just check app.exe.Webview2 folder is generated in your exe folder path.
2. is webviewloder.dll is present or not ?

and if you want simple way to install the webview2 while installation then just download the microsoftWebviewSetup.exe and include the exe file in your custom action

steps:

1. create a setup project
2. in application folder add your wpf exe and webview2 exe
3. right click on project -> View -> custom action
4. open the custom action -> Install -> add the webView2.exe
5. run the setup.exe it will install the webviewruntime also

Comment: from where i can get the microsoftWebviewSetup.exe ?

Comment: you can get it from the link mentioned above, it will tell you 2 ways also. or else simplest way is mentioned above but you have to add some validation bcz this setup will execute the installation of webview2 everytime you install

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tried the ways mentioned in Webview distribution  link but not worked for my case. I will try your steps

Comment: Worked !! Thanks @simpleCitizen_